# How to set pdf title in Servlet Response

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, response

I am trying to set the Title of the Browser as the PDF document Title. 
Though the pdf generates correctly, i get the Title randomly.

`response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0L);`

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + title + ".pdf");

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(bArray.length);
    try {
                   response.getOutputStream().write(bArray);
        response.getOutputStream().close();}
```

Could someone please help me out here to override the pdf title

Comment: `I get the Title randomly` - what do you mean by "randomly". Can you provide examples?

Comment: [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Object_Headers.html#title) states there is a "Title" header field, did you try setting that?

Comment: i get this pdf from an external third party tool. this title comes as per that tool. I want to override this title and set it as the document title, so that the browser gets the document title

Comment: yes Title is a markup code ... im not sure how do i set it here in the response

Comment: No, the page says there's a `Title: whatever` header which is "isomorphic" to the HTML tag. I didn't use it myself but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the title while at the same time sending a file down to the browser. For the browser to change the "page" title, it needs to actually render an HTML document (ie. it needs to render a page).

But there is a workaround to achieve it.
Redirect it to a page that renders out the title, . And from that page trigger  the browser over to the download.

Comment: I am redirecting the response to a new window.. I need to set the title for this new window. Can u help with some code snippet

Answer (score -1):

Try this !!!!

In html/jsp page:

```
<a href="pdf/filename.pdf">
```

In servlet:

```
 String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);//filename.pdf
```

Also you cen remove .pdf from title by simple java operation.

Comment: my_window = window.open('/test/servlet/PDFServlet?documentId=123'); My code is not in href ..Also my title needs to be set in response .. as it needs to be displayed on browser window

Answer (score -1):

```
content-disposition: attachment
```

Similar question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829491/set-filename-of-the-pdf-that-is-streamed-back-to-the-browser)

Comment: i have to make it inline .. cannot change to attachment

Answer (score -1):

**Replace your code with**

`response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + title + ".pdf");`

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setContentLength(bArray.length);
try {
               response.getOutputStream().write(bArray);
    response.getOutputStream().close();}
```

Read answer description here 
[set metadata response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download)